# LINQ-to-SQL code works fine in Windows 7 but bombs in Windows XP. Why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have the following little import application, basically it...

1. connects to a hosted SQL server,
2. pulls down a sign-up list,
3. inserts to staging table,
4. checks for duplicates,
5. filters non-dupes into main table.

Every Windows 7 box it ran on had no problem. With Windows XP, it gets to the first bit of LINQ and throws all kinds of crazy LINQ errors. I came to this conclusion by testing my program on approx. 10 computers. I replicated the problem by running the code on an XP virtual machine at home... same place (LINQ insert, see code below) where it crashed previously.

### The error:

> Error Occurred Getting Record From Remote Server: Details =>
>
> **`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`** (`0x80131904`):
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> ```
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
> at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
> at AfocImport.Program.Main(String[] args)
> ```

### The code:

(Criticism is welcome, I'm still learning)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AfocImport
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var LNQ = new LNQDataContext();

        var sel = from a in LNQ.Respondents
                  where a.dateenter > Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())
                  select new
                             {
                                 a.recordid,a.phone,a.wphone,a.wphone_ext,a.fax,a.cellphone,a.email,a.area_code,a.area_code_w,a.lname,a.fname,a.address,a.city,a.state,a.zip,a.county,a.address_w,a.city_w,a.state_w,
                                 a.zip_w,a.county_w,a.employer,a.Occ_title,a.jobcode,a.hours,a.datebirth,a.gender,a.maritalstatus,a.income,a.education,a.race,a.Party,a.typehome,a.spousejobcode,a.spousehours,a.childgen1,
                                 a.childbd1,a.childgen2,a.childbd2,a.childgen3,a.childbd3,a.childgen4,a.childbd4,a.childgen5,a.childbd5,a.childgen6,a.childbd6,a.resp_type,a.dateenter,a.dateupdated,a.referred_by_resp,
                                 a.Pro_resp,a.Caution_Flag,a.last_selection,a.last_participation,a.number_parts,a.calling_note,a.notes,a.CC1,a.CC2,a.CC3,a.CC4,a.CC5,a.CC6,a.CC7,a.CC8,a.CC9,a.CC10,a.CC11,a.CC12,a.CC13,
                                 a.CC14,a.CC15,a.CC16,a.CC17,a.CC18,a.CC19,a.CC20,a.CC21,a.CC22,a.CC23,a.CC24,a.CC25,a.CC26,a.CC27,a.CC28,a.CC29,a.CC30,a.CC31,a.CC32,a.CC33,a.CC34,a.CC35,a.CC36,a.CC37,a.CC38,a.CC39,
                                 a.CC40,a.CC41,a.CC42,a.CC43,a.CC44,a.CC45,a.CC46,a.CC47,a.CC48,a.CC49,a.CC50,a.c_brand,a.c_flavor,a.c_length,a.c_type,a.c_past_purchases,a.c_other_brands,a.car_make_1,a.car_model_1,
                                 a.car_year_1,a.car_options_1,a.car_make_2,a.car_model_2,a.car_year_2,a.car_options_2,
                             };

        var LNQH = new LNQHDataContext();

        foreach (var a in sel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tInserting to Staging: " + a.fname + " " + a.lname);
            var r = new RespondentStaging
                        {
                            recordid = a.recordid,phone = a.phone,wphone = a.wphone,wphone_ext = a.wphone_ext,fax = a.fax,cellphone = a.cellphone,email = a.email,area_code = a.area_code,area_code_w = a.area_code_w,
                            lname = a.lname,fname = a.fname,address = a.address,city = a.city,state = a.state,zip = a.zip,county = a.county,address_w = a.address_w,city_w = a.city_w,state_w = a.state_w,zip_w = a.zip_w,
                            county_w = a.county_w,employer = a.employer,Occ_title = a.Occ_title,jobcode = a.jobcode,hours = a.hours,datebirth = a.datebirth,gender = a.gender,maritalstatus = a.maritalstatus,income = a.income,
                            education = a.education,race = a.race,Party = a.Party,typehome = a.typehome,spousejobcode = a.spousejobcode,spousehours = a.spousehours,childgen1 = a.childgen1,childbd1 = a.childbd1,childgen2 = a.childgen2,
                            childbd2 = a.childbd2,childgen3 = a.childgen3,childbd3 = a.childbd3,childgen4 = a.childgen4,childbd4 = a.childbd4,childgen5 = a.childgen5,childbd5 = a.childbd5,childgen6 = a.childgen6,childbd6 = a.childbd6,
                            resp_type = a.resp_type,dateenter = a.dateenter,dateupdated = a.dateupdated,referred_by_resp = a.referred_by_resp,Pro_resp = a.Pro_resp,Caution_Flag = a.Caution_Flag,last_selection = a.last_selection,
                            last_participation = a.last_participation,number_parts = a.number_parts,calling_note = a.calling_note,notes = a.notes,CC1 = a.CC1,CC2 = a.CC2,CC3 = a.CC3,CC4 = a.CC4,CC5 = a.CC5,CC6 = a.CC6,CC7 = a.CC7,
                            CC8 = a.CC8,CC9 = a.CC9,CC10 = a.CC10,CC11 = a.CC11,CC12 = a.CC12,CC13 = a.CC13,CC14 = a.CC14,CC15 = a.CC15,CC16 = a.CC16,CC17 = a.CC17,CC18 = a.CC18,CC19 = a.CC19,CC20 = a.CC20,CC21 = a.CC21,CC22 = a.CC22,
                            CC23 = a.CC23,CC24 = a.CC24,CC25 = a.CC25,CC26 = a.CC26,CC27 = a.CC27,CC28 = a.CC28,CC29 = a.CC29,CC30 = a.CC30,CC31 = a.CC31,CC32 = a.CC32,CC33 = a.CC33,CC34 = a.CC34,CC35 = a.CC35,CC36 = a.CC36,CC37 = a.CC37,
                            CC38 = a.CC38,CC39 = a.CC39,CC40 = a.CC40,CC41 = a.CC41,CC42 = a.CC42,CC43 = a.CC43,CC44 = a.CC44,CC45 = a.CC45,CC46 = a.CC46,CC47 = a.CC47,CC48 = a.CC48,CC49 = a.CC49,CC50 = a.CC50,c_brand = a.c_brand,c_flavor = a.c_flavor,
                            c_length = a.c_length,c_type = a.c_type,c_past_purchases = a.c_past_purchases,c_other_brands = a.c_other_brands,car_make_1 = a.car_make_1,car_model_1 = a.car_model_1,car_year_1 = a.car_year_1,car_options_1 = a.car_options_1,
                            car_make_2 = a.car_make_2,car_model_2 = a.car_model_2,car_year_2 = a.car_year_2,car_options_2 = a.car_options_2
                        };

            LNQH.RespondentStagings.InsertOnSubmit(r);

            try
            {
                LNQH.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tError Occurred Getting Record From Remote Server: Details => " + ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        var cnt = Convert.ToInt32(LNQH.RespondentStagings.Count());

        if (cnt != 0)
        {
            List<string> nam;
            List<string> phn;
            List<string> wph;
            List<string> cph;

            List<string> good = new List<string>();
            List<string> bad = new List<string>();

            GetLists(out nam, out phn, out wph, out cph);

            var fln = from a in LNQH.RespondentStagings
                      select new { a.recordid, a.fname, a.lname, a.phone, a.wphone, a.cellphone };

            foreach(var a in fln) //was in parrallel for loop but scraped that
                                      {
                                          if (nam.Contains(a.fname + a.lname) && (phn.Contains(a.phone) || wph.Contains(a.wphone) || cph.Contains(a.cellphone)))
                                          {
                                              //Add To Filter Table  
                                              InsFilter(a.recordid);
                                              bad.Add("\tAdded to Filter Table: " + a.fname + " " + a.lname);
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              //Add To Respondent Table
                                              InsRespondent(a.recordid);
                                              good.Add("\tAdded to Respondent Table: " + a.fname + " " + a.lname);
                                              nam.Add(a.fname + a.lname);
                                              phn.Add(a.phone);
                                              wph.Add(a.wphone);
                                              cph.Add(a.cellphone);
                                          }

                                      }

            Console.WriteLine("The Following Records Have Been Added to the Main Table... ");            
            foreach (var a in good) { Console.WriteLine(a); }
            Console.WriteLine("The Following Records Are Potential Duplicates and Have Been Added to Quarantine ... ");
            foreach (var a in bad) { Console.WriteLine(a); }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Zero Records Inserted ... ");

        }

                using (var con = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx";
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        var del = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.Respondent", con) {CommandType = CommandType.Text};
                        del.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    finally 
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
            }
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void InsFilter(int recid)
    {
        var LNQH = new LNQHDataContext();
        var sel = from a in LNQH.RespondentStagings
                  where a.recordid == recid
                  select new
                  {   a.recordid,a.phone,a.wphone,a.wphone_ext,a.fax,a.cellphone,a.email,a.area_code,a.area_code_w,a.lname,a.fname,a.address,a.city,a.state,a.zip,a.county,a.address_w,a.city_w,a.state_w,a.zip_w,a.county_w,
                      a.employer,a.Occ_title,a.jobcode,a.hours,a.datebirth,a.gender,a.maritalstatus,a.income,a.education,a.race,a.Party,a.typehome,a.spousejobcode,a.spousehours,a.childgen1,a.childbd1,a.childgen2,a.childbd2,
                      a.childgen3,a.childbd3,a.childgen4,a.childbd4,a.childgen5,a.childbd5,a.childgen6,a.childbd6,a.resp_type,a.dateenter,a.dateupdated,a.referred_by_resp,a.Pro_resp,a.Caution_Flag,a.last_selection,a.last_participation,
                      a.number_parts,a.calling_note,a.notes,a.CC1,a.CC2,a.CC3,a.CC4,a.CC5,a.CC6,a.CC7,a.CC8,a.CC9,a.CC10,a.CC11,a.CC12,a.CC13,a.CC14,a.CC15,a.CC16,a.CC17,a.CC18,a.CC19,a.CC20,a.CC21,a.CC22,a.CC23,a.CC24,a.CC25,a.CC26,a.CC27,
                      a.CC28,a.CC29,a.CC30,a.CC31,a.CC32,a.CC33,a.CC34,a.CC35,a.CC36,a.CC37,a.CC38,a.CC39,a.CC40,a.CC41,a.CC42,a.CC43,a.CC44,a.CC45,a.CC46,a.CC47,a.CC48,a.CC49,a.CC50,a.c_brand,a.c_flavor,a.c_length,a.c_type,a.c_past_purchases,
                      a.c_other_brands,a.car_make_1,a.car_model_1,a.car_year_1,a.car_options_1,a.car_make_2,a.car_model_2,a.car_year_2,a.car_options_2,
                  };

        foreach (var a in sel)
        {
            var f = new RespondentFiltered
                        {
                            phone_Y = a.phone,wphone_Y = a.wphone,wphone_ext_Y = a.wphone_ext,fax_Y = a.fax,cellphone_Y = a.cellphone,email_Y = a.email,area_code_Y = a.area_code,area_code_w_Y = a.area_code_w,lname_Y = a.lname,fname_Y = a.fname,
                            address_Y = a.address,city_Y = a.city,state_Y = a.state,zip_Y = a.zip,county_Y = a.county,address_w_Y = a.address_w,city_w_Y = a.city_w,state_w_Y = a.state_w,zip_w_Y = a.zip_w,county_w_Y = a.county_w,employer_Y = a.employer,
                            Occ_title_Y = a.Occ_title,jobcode_Y = a.jobcode,hours_Y = a.hours,datebirth_Y = a.datebirth,gender_Y = a.gender,maritalstatus_Y = a.maritalstatus,income_Y = a.income,education_Y = a.education,race_Y = a.race,Party_Y = a.Party,
                            typehome_Y = a.typehome,spousejobcode_Y = a.spousejobcode,spousehours_Y = a.spousehours,childgen1_Y = a.childgen1,childbd1_Y = a.childbd1,childgen2_Y = a.childgen2,childbd2_Y = a.childbd2,childgen3_Y = a.childgen3,childbd3_Y = a.childbd3,
                            childgen4_Y = a.childgen4,childbd4_Y = a.childbd4,childgen5_Y = a.childgen5,childbd5_Y = a.childbd5,childgen6_Y = a.childgen6,childbd6_Y = a.childbd6,resp_type_Y = a.resp_type,dateenter_Y = a.dateenter,dateupdated_Y = a.dateupdated,
                            referred_by_resp_Y = a.referred_by_resp,Pro_resp_Y = a.Pro_resp,Caution_Flag_Y = a.Caution_Flag,last_selection_Y = a.last_selection,last_participation_Y = a.last_participation,number_parts_Y = a.number_parts,calling_note_Y = a.calling_note,
                            notes_Y = a.notes,CC1_Y = a.CC1,CC2_Y = a.CC2,CC3_Y = a.CC3,CC4_Y = a.CC4,CC5_Y = a.CC5,CC6_Y = a.CC6,CC7_Y = a.CC7,CC8_Y = a.CC8,CC9_Y = a.CC9,CC10_Y = a.CC10,CC11_Y = a.CC11,CC12_Y = a.CC12,CC13_Y = a.CC13,CC14_Y = a.CC14,CC15_Y = a.CC15,
                            CC16_Y = a.CC16,CC17_Y = a.CC17,CC18_Y = a.CC18,CC19_Y = a.CC19,CC20_Y = a.CC20,CC21_Y = a.CC21,CC22_Y = a.CC22,CC23_Y = a.CC23,CC24_Y = a.CC24,CC25_Y = a.CC25,CC26_Y = a.CC26,CC27_Y = a.CC27,CC28_Y = a.CC28,CC29_Y = a.CC29,CC30_Y = a.CC30,
                            CC31_Y = a.CC31,CC32_Y = a.CC32,CC33_Y = a.CC33,CC34_Y = a.CC34,CC35_Y = a.CC35,CC36_Y = a.CC36,CC37_Y = a.CC37,CC38_Y = a.CC38,CC39_Y = a.CC39,CC40_Y = a.CC40,CC41_Y = a.CC41,CC42_Y = a.CC42,CC43_Y = a.CC43,CC44_Y = a.CC44,CC45_Y = a.CC45,
                            CC46_Y = a.CC46,CC47_Y = a.CC47,CC48_Y = a.CC48,CC49_Y = a.CC49,CC50_Y = a.CC50,c_brand_Y = a.c_brand,c_flavor_Y = a.c_flavor,c_length_Y = a.c_length,c_type_Y = a.c_type,c_past_purchases_Y = a.c_past_purchases,c_other_brands_Y = a.c_other_brands,
                            car_make_1_Y = a.car_make_1,car_model_1_Y = a.car_model_1,car_year_1_Y = a.car_year_1,car_options_1_Y = a.car_options_1,car_make_2_Y = a.car_make_2,car_model_2_Y = a.car_model_2,car_year_2_Y = a.car_year_2,car_options_2_Y = a.car_options_2
                        };

            LNQH.RespondentFiltereds.InsertOnSubmit(f);

            try { LNQH.SubmitChanges(); }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tError Occurred Moving Record To Staging Database: Details => " + ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        var del = from b in LNQH.RespondentStagings
                  where b.recordid == recid
                  select b;

        foreach (var b in del)
        {
            LNQH.RespondentStagings.DeleteOnSubmit(b);    
        }
        try { LNQH.SubmitChanges(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tError Occurred Deleting Record From Staging Database: Details => " + ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static void InsRespondent(int recid)
    {
            var LNQH = new LNQHDataContext();
            var sel = from a in LNQH.RespondentStagings
                      where a.recordid == recid
                      select new
                                 {   a.recordid,a.phone,a.wphone,a.wphone_ext,a.fax,a.cellphone,a.email,a.area_code,a.area_code_w,a.lname,a.fname,a.address,a.city,a.state,a.zip,a.county,a.address_w,a.city_w,a.state_w,a.zip_w,
                                     a.county_w,a.employer,a.Occ_title,a.jobcode,a.hours,a.datebirth,a.gender,a.maritalstatus,a.income,a.education,a.race,a.Party,a.typehome,a.spousejobcode,a.spousehours,a.childgen1,a.childbd1,a.childgen2,
                                     a.childbd2,a.childgen3,a.childbd3,a.childgen4,a.childbd4,a.childgen5,a.childbd5,a.childgen6,a.childbd6,a.resp_type,a.dateenter,a.dateupdated,a.referred_by_resp,a.Pro_resp,a.Caution_Flag,a.last_selection,
                                     a.last_participation,a.number_parts,a.calling_note,a.notes,a.CC1,a.CC2,a.CC3,a.CC4,a.CC5,a.CC6,a.CC7,a.CC8,a.CC9,a.CC10,a.CC11,a.CC12,a.CC13,a.CC14,a.CC15,a.CC16,a.CC17,a.CC18,a.CC19,a.CC20,a.CC21,a.CC22,
                                     a.CC23,a.CC24,a.CC25,a.CC26,a.CC27,a.CC28,a.CC29,a.CC30,a.CC31,a.CC32,a.CC33,a.CC34,a.CC35,a.CC36,a.CC37,a.CC38,a.CC39,a.CC40,a.CC41,a.CC42,a.CC43,a.CC44,a.CC45,a.CC46,a.CC47,a.CC48,a.CC49,a.CC50,a.c_brand,
                                     a.c_flavor,a.c_length,a.c_type,a.c_past_purchases,a.c_other_brands,a.car_make_1,a.car_model_1,a.car_year_1,a.car_options_1,a.car_make_2,a.car_model_2,a.car_year_2,a.car_options_2,
                                 };

            foreach (var a in sel)
            {
                #region SQL_INSERT

                using (var con = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx";
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        var cmd = new SqlCommand("INS_Respond_Local", con) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
                        var del = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.RespondentStaging WHERE recordid = '" + recid + "'", con) {CommandType = CommandType.Text};

                        #region DeclareSQL

            //Bunchof Markup

                        #endregion

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        del.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    finally 
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }

                #endregion
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetLists(out List<string> nam, out List<string> phn, out List<string> wph, out List<string> cph)
    {
        var nam_x = new List<String>();
        var phn_x = new List<String>();
        var wph_x = new List<String>();
        var cph_x = new List<String>();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx";
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT fname + lname as 'N', phone as 'P', wphone as 'W', cellphone as 'C' FROM dbo.Respondent WHERE fname is not null and lname is not null order by fname + lname", con) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
            try
            {
                var red = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (red.Read())
                {
                    nam_x.Add(red["N"].ToString());
                    phn_x.Add(red["P"].ToString());
                    wph_x.Add(red["W"].ToString());
                    cph_x.Add(red["C"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally { con.Close(); }
        }

        nam = nam_x;
        phn = phn_x;
        wph = wph_x;
        cph = cph_x;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the specific question? Please be as specific as possible, including providing the complete text of any exceptions or errors you're receiving.

Comment: wow this is a maintenance nightmare - look into something like AutoMapper for property mapping

Comment: Also, if it's throwing "crazy LINQ errors" -- Have you confirmed that the .NET Framework 3.5 is installed on those machines?

Comment: I didn't have anything to debug the code with onsite, the .net error i got on the xp was all hex and in my haste I didn't copy it.  I know dumb ... I'm going to try to get them to send to me tomm.  Really wondering if there is an explanation for the phenomenon i'm seeing with it running on win7 box and not xp.  It has no com or unmanaged code.  All have .net 4.0 similiar cpu ???

Comment: About your code: try to separate code to classes. What you do is procedural code using static methods as procedural functions. This is actually not OO code.

Comment: would such a small utility warrant the use of OO code ?

Comment: @DBM yes all machines are .net 4.0 core2 ...

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna You were using the TPL, so I'm *assuming* the application was built for .NET 4, but can you confirm?

Comment: yes sir ... p.s. I'm sorry for infuriating so many with this question lol.

Comment: Can you ping the SQL server from the XP box?

Comment: yes sir, first thing i checked

Comment: what is your connection string? What protocol do you use to connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a linq error (ok, it is brought to you by linq but it simply a sql server connection problem).

This is the root cause:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlExcept ion

> (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connect ion to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

You need to check your connection string (web.config). Is it pointing to the right server. If you use the same connection from sql server management studio can you connect?

You need to check your firewall: perhaps it is blocking your TCP ports for sql server

Other suggestions: [Why did a network-related or instance-specific error occur while establishing a connection to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391503/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne)