# Mvc .../Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f Error then publish to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC project created in visual studio 2012 all work fine with Debug, but then I publish it... I have an Error.

[image]

If I comment the Autentification the project work good and show all data from database. thank you a lot for help

Comment: I think this can Help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391503/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting from Windows Machine A to Windows Machine B (server with SQL Server installed) and are getting this error, you need to do the following:

On Machine B:
....

complet source: [Why did a network-related or instance-specific error occur while establishing a connection to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391503/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne)

Comment: Thank you a lot for help and thank you for down vote ... the best programmers