# Can't connect to SQL Server 2003 error 121

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is the error I am receiving when connecting to our SQL Server 2003 database

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)
>   "the semaphore time out has expired"

but when I try to connect using another pc its working

This is a weird error message "the semaphore time out has expired" and I've tried all the possible solution related to the link that you gave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391503/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne)

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2003** - we have versions 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and 2016 - so which one are you *really* talking about??

Comment: haha im so sorry for the mistake, its sql server 2008

Comment: the 2003 is the version of windows server