# Client Access to sql Server 2008 Express Database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have trouble connecting my database via another computer. On my server computer, everything works, but if I copy my application to a client I can't connect. (Of course I can start management studio, server configuration)

This is my connection string:

```
 DS_SDF = "IPAddress\someinstance;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=somedatabase; User ID=Someuser; Password=Somepassword;"
```

What I already did:

- I checked my server properties

  - remote connections are accepted
  - TCP/IP is activated
- I tried with a port which I added to my windows firewall
- I also stopped my firewall, virus scanner, Cisco remote client, while connecting

Because the connection string should work, here my questions:

- How can I see, which port is used?
- Can I check via commandbox from client to server if I can reach the server instance?
- What else can I do, to solve the problem?
- Can it be some network problem? I can connect to my client computer via win explorer.

Here is the error which I get:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: have you tried adding another user to your sql management studio? I had a similar problem where I had to add another use in order for it to work, also with the connection string, try something like this `"SERVER = servername; DATABASE = mydatabase; USER ID = username; PASSWORD = password;` as long as all the required processes are running, it should hopefully connect.

Comment: yes I already tried this, just again as you suggested, same error. I don't know where to look, so I gonna install another pc as database server and I hope that will do. It must have to do with the computerconfíguration I guess

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15417069/832052

Comment: Unless you've changed it, SQL Server uses port 1433 for connections

Comment: @djv that showed me the way, I did everything there, but I tried before doing the portfilter, so my firewall had blocked the accessing notebook. After allow the notebook again, everything worked. puh

Answer (score 0):

Might be interesting for other blind developers.
I found the solution, it was an issue of sequence. I put the ports in, but before I had already tested and the effect was, that my eset-firewall blocked the accessing notebook and the sql-server-services.

So the ports were correct, but the notebook and services were on the blacklist. See picture above, I fixed that, and now it works. 
[image]