# sql connection over VPN in WPF program

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, vpn, sqlconnection

I'm trying to connect to a remote server via VPN, and I have connected to the VPN successfully, and when I'm using management studio, it's also all good and well, but when I'm trying to connect via my WPF program I'm getting this error
On `connection.Open();`

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.)"}

and this is my Connection string as copied from visual studio

```
Data Source=192.168.232.10\PRI2014,4443;Integrated Security=True;User ID=c_Vision;Password=********;Connect Timeout=15; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=True; Trusted_Connection=True;
```

i have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523723/getting-error-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-estab#answer-47524004) for answers

Answer (score 0):

Port number should be placed after Ip

```
  Data Source=192.168.232.10,4443\PRI2014;Integrated Security=True;User ID=c_Vision;Password=********;Connect Timeout=15; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=True; Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: Do you have any firewall on your client? A possibility that you have an restriction for your wpf application. Your firewall could only allow to management studio for using 4443 port.

Comment: found the solution, there was a typo in the Connection string