# C# local database error

Tags: c#, database, connection

i am having an error while connecting the local service database of C# in VS 2017. The app is just for testing and the error i am having the con.open() line. I have placed a data gridview in the app with dataset and it is showing all the values inside the db in gridview but when i use my button to execute the INSERT Query it shows up an error. This is the error below

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
>   - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid. )'

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \\Users\\Shahrukh Khan\\source\\repos\\checkingsetup\\testingdb\\Database123.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into table1 values('"+textBox1.Text+"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from table1";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did a network-related or instance-specific error occur while establishing a connection to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391503/why-did-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occur-while-establishing-a)

Comment: You have a space after `C:` in your connection string.

Comment: That connection string is wrong; you want either `"...\\MSSQLLocalDB;..."` or `@"...\MSSQLLocalDB;..."`, not both.