# Cannot connect SQL Server with instance - SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, remote-server

I have a very strange and very frustating problem:

I'm trying to connect to an remote SQL Server Database, and i gotta some errors, like:

I've tried to connect to an specific remote SQL that has only one instance (SQL Server 2008). When i use the correct connection string, with server address and instance name, o get the following error:

[image]

But when i remove the instance name, it works:

[image]

Calling with customer's service from this server, they said that this server has only one SQL, so it allows you to connect without instance.

But my real problem is that i'm trying to connect to another server that has more than only one instances of SQL, so i'm getting the same old error:

[image]

And if i remove the instance, i get login error, cos my user and passwd was not found at default sql server.

[image]

I have tried several changes:

1. I've changed my Management Studio from 2017 to 2014.
2. I've formatted my computer last night, trying to solve this problem,
   but i still got the same errors
3. I've asked to some friends to connect to this same server, exacly
   the same way that i'm trying, and they sucessfully connected.

I really dont know what I'm doing wrong. Somebody knows how to help?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried figuring out what port the instance is listening? (is it even listening to TCP/IP?) and are the relevant ports open in the OS firewall? Try connecting to said port rather than the instance name. (not ideal, but sometimes this is necessary when the SQLBrowser service is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did a network-related or instance-specific error occur while establishing a connection to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1391503/1260204)

Comment: Read through these suggested duplicates, there are a couple of well written troubleshooting answers.